# Origen de la expresión "de tomo y lomo"

Tags: etimología, expresiones

El DLE recoge la expresión ***[de tomo y lomo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a01DbdA)*** como:

> 1. loc. adj. coloq. De consideración o importancia.
> 2. loc. adj. coloq. desus. De mucho bulto y peso.

Preguntándome estoy por el origen de esta expresión, dado que la segunda acepción hace referencia a algo de mucho bulto, por lo que la expresión me hace pensar en tomos de una enciclopedia, con sus respectivos lomos visibles y haciendo bulto en la estantería.

Sin embargo, la propia palabra *tomo* tiene una acepción en desuso ("importancia, valor y estima") que podría haber dado origen a la primera acepción de la citada expresión ("de consideración o importancia").

Si nos vamos al *Diccionario de Autoridades*, vemos que la acepción mencionada de *tomo* no estaba en desuso por el siglo XVIII:

> Metaphoricamente significa importancia, valor, y estima.

Y cita como ejemplo:

> Hallarémos que son unas cosas, que bien apuradas no tienen *tomo*, ni substancia ninguna.

En Covarrubias no encuentro nada parecido, como mucho este fragmento:

> Cosa de tomo, lo que hinche la mano, y la voluntad. [Henchir: vale llenar.]

Si algo que es "cosa de tomo" lo es porque llena la voluntad, es que es algo realmente de importancia. Por la misma época en la que se publicó el Covarrubias se empiezan a encontrar los primeros casos de la expresión que nos ocupa en el CORDE:

> *Señor, yo busco las mujeres que lo sean de tomo y lomo.*
>
> Agustín de Rojas Villadrando, "El viaje entretenido", 1603 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Llególe a Bartolo al alma / que es por extremo celoso, / y teme al competidor, / que es mozo de tomo y lomo.*
>
> Gabriel Lobo Lasso de la Vega, "Manojuelo de romances", 1601 (España).

Se ve por los ejemplos de entonces que la expresión se aplicaba a personas, y la acepción aplicada a personas de *[lomo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NalcFKk)* es "parte inferior y central de la espalda". En todo caso, en el *Diccionario de Autoridades* se recoge que la expresión ya se usaba en el siglo XVIII aplicada a cosas además de a personas.

Mi suposición es que la expresión no hacía referencia a los libros, como yo pensaba, sino que hacía referencia a personas que eran gente importante tanto en el plano intelectual ("cosa de tomo") como en el físico ("tenían un buen lomo"), usando la palabra *lomo* por su parecido con *tomo* y creando así una expresión que perduraría en el tiempo.

¿Es mi suposición correcta? ¿Se conocen casos de la expresión anteriores al siglo XVII? ¿Es la expresión "cosa de tomo" (que sí se encuentra en textos del siglo XVI) originaria de "de tomo y lomo"? ¿Hay casos anteriores al *Diccionario de Autoridades* de la expresión "de tomo y lomo" aplicada a cosas?

Comment: Me parece más lógico suponer que ambos términos se refieren al tomo y lomo de un libro. Los libros de ediciónes más económicas no disponían de cubierta dura ni de "lomo"  y únicamente las obras muy extensas estaban divididas en "tomos", supongo que de ahí vendrá.